# modal view, white bar on top of on-screen keyboard in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios5, presentmodalviewcontroller, landscape-portrait

Navigation based app, launched a modalview with code like:

```
[self presentModalViewController:bookmarkAddViewController animated:YES];
[bookmarkAddViewController release];
```

In portrait mode, keyboard raised, no problem; but in landscape mode, there is a white bar on top of raised keyboard. Why this happen, and how to fix it?!

PS: not able to attach image due to lack of points. sigh... why SO making things so difficult while its whole purpose is trying to help people.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your autoresize mask is not set properly. Double check this in the nib. Select the main view for bookmarkAddViewController and click on the ruler. Make sure the resize masks bits are set correctly (all on).

That might not be the problem, but worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks @logancautrell, in fact the problem is in the nib. I choose 'landscape' mode, and I see the white bar, just make my table view bigger and the problem is solved.